# jQuery js file breaking css code when linked after the css stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

Got a strange one here that I only just managed to weed out:

I've got css code which produces a multilevel dropdown menu. I decided to implement some jQuery on the same page for a calendar date picker. Got this working but have only just noticed that the css drop down menu has stopped working only in IE 6 (I know, old, 2% usage, but I would like to get to the bottom of this).

Anyway, after a lot of trial and error, I've worked out that it all depends on where the `<script src="/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>` line is. It seems that if the jquery library is called after the css (both stylesheets and page specific stuff in the head section), the css doesn't work, no menus appear when they are hovered. However, if I have the jquery library included above the css, it all works fine.

Just wondering, is there something about .js and .css that I'm unaware of in terms of the order in which they can be called?

This is the css code:

```
(if IE)

body {
behavior: url(csshover.htc);
font-size: 100%;
} 

#stuartFilter ul li {float: left; width: 100%;}
#stuartFilter ul li a {height: 1%;} 

#stuartFilter a, #stuartFilter h2 {
font: bold 11px/16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
(end if)

#stuartFilter a img{border:none;
}

#stuartFilter {
width: auto;
background: rgb(250, 240, 230);
float: left;
}   

#stuartFilter ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 7.5em;
float: left;
background: url(downArrow.png) no-repeat 100% 75%;
}

#stuartFilter a, #stuartFilter h2 {
font: bold 11px/16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
display: block;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ccc #888 #555 #bbb;
margin: 0px;
padding: 6px 6px;
}

#stuartFilter h2 {
color: #fff;
background: #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#stuartFilter a {
color: #000;
background: rgb(250, 250, 229);
text-decoration: none;
}

#stuartFilter a:hover {
color: #a00;
background: #fff;
}

#stuartFilter li {position: relative;}

#stuartFilter ul ul {
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
left: 0%;
width: 12em;
}

#stuartFilter ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
//width: 11em;
}

div#stuartFilter ul ul,
div#stuartFilter ul li:hover ul ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul li:hover ul ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul li:hover ul ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul li:hover ul ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul ul li:hover ul ul
{display: none;}

div#stuartFilter ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul ul ul li:hover ul
{display: block;}
```

I have just noticed also, that when I use the non-minified version of jquery, it works fine. Strange no?!

Comment: *"... in IE 6 (I know, old, 2% usage..."* More like 10% in [non-development circles](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2).

Comment: People are unlikely to be able to help you without seeing the CSS that's breaking, although I'm having trouble imagining how jQuery would break CSS in any case (it has to be possible, I'm just not immediately seeing how).

Comment: Yeah, that's the original reason I didn't upload it, since I was thinking there was a more generic higher level issue than my actual code. Anyway, I've updated my post with the css code.

Comment: @T.J. Oh that's hideous. Why will IE6 not just _leave_.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a little off-topic, but that CSS in your example is just ridiculous:

```
div#stuartFilter ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#stuartFilter ul ul ul ul ul ul li:hover ul
{display: block;}
```

Which is more important, however, is that it slows the page rendering down a lot ([especially in older browsers](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/)), since the selectors are all interpreted from right to left.

The problem can easily be solved by adding a level-specific classes to menu lists and items, so the selectors would be something like this:

```
.item_firstlevel:hover .list_secondlevel,
.item_secondlevel:hover .list_thirdlevel
```

And so on.

Comment: Mmm, I agree it's ridiculous but it was requires for backwards compatibility. I'll give your method a go, but I suspect it won't work in ie6.

I do have a problem with ajax pages rendering extremely slow in some versions of ie when SSL is enabled, but I don't think your fix will sort that unfortunately.

Hey, thanks for answering so late after my posting the original problem! I'll let you know if it works in all browsers...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your codes is used, but a lot of IE6 CSS menus used javascript to add a helper class to help with hover states on non-link items (e.g., html tags that aren't an a tag). Without seeing more, I'd guess that the position of the jQuery is affecting that other JavaScript, if you have it.

Can you paste the html/css for your menu?

Comment: Of course, I've updated the original post. Regards what you said, the csshover.htc is javascript, so maybe that's it?

Comment: It could be. Are you using any jQuery to affect hover/mouseover/mouseenter/etc on any elements within your menu? I don't see any classes used in your CSS so my initial guess (helper classes via JavaScript) isn't the issue, but I still guess/suspect that something between the .htc file and your jQuery/JavaScript is conflicting.

Comment: The elements are just elements (links), there's no javascript in there. But I bet you're right, I think there's some conflict between csshover.htc and jquery.js.